# Cannot get a picture from my local computer to show up on my website

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and have constructed a simple site with html and css. I attempted to add a picture from my local computer to the site. The picture file was placed into the same folder as my html and css files. However, when my page loads, the picture does not show up. Why might this be? this is my html code. Suggestions on what might be wrong are greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css"/>
<title>My Professional Site</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Jon Doe</h1>
<h2>Learning to code.</h2>
<img src = "IMG_0523.jpg" alt="Sorry No Picute Available"    style="width:300px;height:300px;">
<p>"Trying to learn to code." </p>
<footer>Contact Info: jd@mail.com   555-5555</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in what directory did you put your image file?

Comment: make sure you point it to the right directory or path

Comment: can you show us your directory structure?

Comment: And are you developing the site locally?

Comment: Your html file and `IMG_0523.jpg` should be in same directory and if you want it to be in other directory than you need to change img src.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. Thanks to everyone for kindly contributing.

Answer (score 0):

Directory structure 1

Root

- images

  - IMG_0523.jpg
- index.html

Access it with `images/`

```
<img src = "images/IMG_0523.jpg" alt="Sorry No Picute Available" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
```

Directory structure 2

Root

- IMG_0523.jpg
- index.html

Then access it directly

```
<img src = "IMG_0523.jpg" alt="Sorry No Picute Available" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
```

Directory structure 3

Root

- images

  - IMG_0523.jpg
- pages

  - index.html

Then access it with `../images/`

```
<img src = "../images/IMG_0523.jpg" alt="Sorry No Picute Available" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
```

Use relative path instead

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I was able to figure out the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Try the absolute path of the image, rather than relative path to the image. absolute paths look something like this. C:\images\IMG_0523.jpg

Comment: absolute path isn't good. You should put all the files inside the working directory.